# Displaying data from a database using jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database

I'm trying to display specific parts of a Cloudant database. This database contains many separate documents, and each document contains a category called "results". I'm trying to display whatever is in results. Each document is identified by its own id. I tried using the get() method in jQuery, but unfortunately it is not running successfully.

```
 function grabData(){
  var url = 'https://cloudant.com/futon/document.html?acharya%2Ftoxtweet/ff558f75077e8c758523cd3bd8ffdf88';
   $.get(url, function(data) {
     $('.result').html(data);
       alert("Data loaded: " + data);
});
}
grabData();
```

I'm not entirely sure where I went wrong...Should I consider using SQL instead of ajax?

Comment: what do you get as alert ?

Comment: What is the content type you are expecting? default is html.

Comment: What type of data is there **category called "results"**?

Comment: I got nothing as alert. It's just a blank page when I run it

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using is returning an entire webpage.

Your jQuery code is looking for an element on the current page with a class name of `result` and trying to change it's inner HTML to the response from the URL.

You didn't provide any additional code to look at, but I would assume that is not what you were expecting it to do.

I assume you are wanting to parse through the entire url, but in your current code the page will be processed as a raw string and not a DOM object.  So you would have to parse through that string with regular expressions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue it this:

replace this:

```
grabData();
```

with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    grabData();
});
```

or more shortened:

```
$(function(){
    grabData();
});
```